# Paytm merchant page not comming after clicking pay now button

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, integration, paytm

I have created paytm payment gateway using  "require anandsiddharth/laravel-paytm-wallet" package in laravel. and i have used the following demo merchant details:

```
YOUR_MERCHANT_ID=DIY12386817555501617

YOUR_MERCHANT_KEY=bKMfNxPPf_QdZppa

YOUR_WEBSITE=DIYtestingweb

YOUR_CHANNEL=WEB

YOUR_INDUSTRY_TYPE=Retail
```

below is my ordercontroller:

```html
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use PaytmWallet;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\EventRegistration;


class OrderController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * Redirect the user to the Payment Gateway.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function register()
    {
        return view('register');
    }


    /**
     * Redirect the user to the Payment Gateway.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function order(Request $request)
    {


        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'mobile_no' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
        ]);


        $input = $request->all();
        $input['order_id'] = $request->mobile_no.rand(1,100);
        $input['fee'] = 50;


        EventRegistration::create($input);


        $payment = PaytmWallet::with('receive');
        $payment->prepare([
          'order' => $input['order_id'],
          'user' => 'your paytm user',
          'mobile_number' => 'your paytm number',
          'email' => 'your paytm email',
          'amount' => $input['fee'],
          'callback_url' => url('api/payment/status')
        ]);
        return $payment->receive();
    }


    /**
     * Obtain the payment information.
     *
     * @return Object
     */
    public function paymentCallback()
    {
        $transaction = PaytmWallet::with('receive');


        $response = $transaction->response();
        $order_id = $transaction->getOrderId();


        if($transaction->isSuccessful()){
          EventRegistration::where('order_id',$order_id)->update(['status'=>2, 'transaction_id'=>$transaction->getTransactionId()]);


          dd('Payment Successfully Paid.');
        }else if($transaction->isFailed()){
          EventRegistration::where('order_id',$order_id)->update(['status'=>1, 'transaction_id'=>$transaction->getTransactionId()]);
          dd('Payment Failed.');
        }
    }
}
```

but after clicking the submit button,am it show "redirecting to paytm merchant page,please wait" but i am taken to a blank page with url http://localhost:8000/api/payment/status
How can i get the merchant page when i click submit button?

Comment: You can try echoing `$transaction->getResponseMessage();` in your payment callback to see what's wrong in your code.

Comment: i think there is something like https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum url to be added in my code. but i dont know how to add t. do you know?

Comment: You can drop an email at : payments.onboarding@paytm.com

Comment: @kingkhan Please remove original merchant key from the question.